# Density of sums of $k$th powers

Tags: number-theory

Fix a positive integer $k$. Is it true that every sufficiently large integer can be written as $\sum_{x\in S}x^k$ for some $S\subseteq\mathbb N$? If not, can we bound the asymptotic density of numbers of this form?

There are $2^n$ subsets of $\{1^k,\dots,n^k\}$, and the sum of every such subset is less than $\sum_{i=1}^ni^k<\frac{(n+1)^{k+1}}{k+1}$, so for sufficiently large $n$ we must have many collisions. But are the sums all "bunched up" on specific values for some reason, or are they "locally uniformly distributed" so that almost every value is hit?

Comment: This is [Waring's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waring%27s_problem) except that in the original it did not demand that all the powers be distinct.  At the end of the article it gives a limit that $G(k)\le k\log k +k\log \log k +Ck$ for some constant $C$.

Comment: Thanks! In Waring's problem, since repeated summands are allowed, it's clear that every number can be represented if we allow arbitrarily many terms in the sum. I'm wondering whether this is also true if the terms must be distinct. (I'm hoping this is easier than the Waring-type problem of bounding the number of terms needed.)

Comment: But Waring's problem shows that for a given $k$ there is an upper limit of the number of terms required.  I suspect that as the number gets large very few duplicates are found, but I don't know that.  If there is just one pair, you can express one of them as a sum of $k^{th}$ powers to get a solution with twice as many terms.